# Excel cannot open the file "filename.xlsm" because the file format or file extension is not valid?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

In Excel 2007, I get this error when I try to run a script a friend posted to the web.  I have heard of no one else having trouble.

Any ideas what might be going on here?

Comment: Sounds like there's probably something incorrect with that specific script in your specific environment...

Comment: Very specific...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your folder options for the .xlsm extension.  That's used by Excel 2007 to indicate a macro-enabled workbook.  If you have an earlier version of Office (or none at all), it may not be set.  You may need to install the [compatibility pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=941b3470-3ae9-4aee-8f43-c6bb74cd1466), re-install or repair Office 2007, or change the folder options.